# Gracenote ODP 03406 Error Message [130]?

Tags: gracenote, entourage

Receiving error message from Gracenote:

```
<RESPONSES>
 <MESSAGE>GCSP: Hello error: [130] Please contact Gracenote ODP 03406 [Name: Yu Song] [App: Arun] support.
 [Gracenote Error 130/74]</MESSAGE>
 <RESPONSE STATUS="ERROR">
 </RESPONSE>
</RESPONSES>
```

developer account issue? Do we need to switch to the new metadata system (entourage or EyeQ I forget which one is the new platform)

Comment: It may be that you have issues with your client ID. Perhaps it is disabled or expired. Entourage and EyeQ are two different products and cannot compare them. If you are just running tests then try deleting the app and recreating them to be assigned a new client ID. Else contact Gracenote as the Error message says.

Answer (score 1):

Your Client ID has expired, you should post this to the [Gracenote Developer forum](https://developer.gracenote.com/forum) in the future when you get this error message. And if you want to use Entourage, you will need to "add a new app" with Entourage platform.